Undetermined Nonvolatile configuration register of MT25QL01GBBB NOR Flash Memory
SOLUTION HERE
ISSUE:
Nonvolatile Configuration Register was set to an undetermined state due to a logical error in the code after sending a write nonvolatile configuration register command.
SOLUTION:
Run power loss recovery sequence which may be done by using SCK, DQ0, and DQ3 pins as GPIO and running the functions provided in the linked solution.
I have an MT25QL01GBBB8ESF-0SIT controlled by an STM32F765VGT6 microcontroller. This was coded using C and the STM32 HAL in the STM32CubeIDE. It was verified working using different SPI commands such as read JEDEC ID, page program, etc. However, after writing to the nonvolatile configuration register, all the tested code stopped working.
Now, I am trying to fix this issue using the power loss recovery function and interface rescue functions of the flash memory. But the flash memory still does not work properly. Would appreciate help in fixing this issue. Let me know if any more information is needed.
I have tried resetting the chip using software and hardware reset pin. I also have an exact duplicate of the chip connected to the same SPI line and verified all the code to be working properly except for the write nonvolatile configuration register function as I did not want to corrupt that chip as well.
Currently, I am trying to implement a power loss recovery and interface rescue function based on the documentation of the flash memory. However, results are still not as expected.
Results:



Results
JEDEC ID
Flag SR




Expected
0x20BA21
0x80


Actual
0xFFFFFF
0xFF



Function that caused the issue:
uint16_t reverse_bits(uint16_t byte)
{
    byte = (byte & 0xFF00) >> 8 | (byte & 0xFF) << 8;
    byte = (byte & 0xF0F0) >> 4 | (byte & 0xF0F) << 4;
    byte = (byte & 0xCCCC) >> 2 | (byte & 0x3333) << 2;
    byte = (byte & 0xAAAA) >> 1 | (byte & 0x555) << 1;
    return byte;
}
void MT25QL_WriteNONVOL(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, MT25QL_FM_NO_t FM, uint16_t reg_val)
{
    uint8_t tData[3];
    reg_val = reverse_bits(reg_val);
    tData[0] = WRITE_NONVOL_CFG_REG_CMD;
    tData[1] = (reg_val) & 0xFF;
    tData[2] = (reg_val >> 8) & 0xFF;

    write_enable(hspi, FM);
    csLOW(FM);
    SPI_Write(hspi, tData, 3);
    csHIGH(FM);

    //write enable reset is automatic
}


Code inside the main function:
  LedToggle();
  MT25QL_PowerLossRecovery(&hspi1, MT25QL_FM1);
  LedToggle();
  HAL_Delay(10);
  LedToggle();
  MT25QL_InterfaceRescue(&hspi1, MT25QL_FM1);
  LedToggle();
  ID = MT25QL_ReadID(&hspi1, MT25QL_FM1);
  FSR = MT25QL_ReadFSR(&hspi1, MT25QL_FM1);
  LedToggle();


Functions used:
HAL_StatusTypeDef MT25QL_InterfaceRescue(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, MT25QL_FM_NO_t FM)
{
    // Step 1: Recovery sequence
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 7); // Example for 7 clock cycles
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 9);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 13);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 17);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 25);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 33);

    // Step 2: Interface rescue
    interface_rescue(hspi, FM);

    return HAL_OK;
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef MT25QL_PowerLossRecovery(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, MT25QL_FM_NO_t FM)
{
    // Step 1: Recovery sequence
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 7); // Example for 7 clock cycles
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 9);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 13);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 17);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 25);
    recovery_sequence(hspi, FM, 33);

    // Step 2: Power Loss Recovery
    power_loss_recovery(hspi, FM);

    return HAL_OK;
}

Helper functions:
static void SPI_Write(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(hspi, data, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

static void SPI_Read(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *data, uint32_t len)
{
    HAL_SPI_Receive(hspi, data, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
static void recovery_sequence(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, MT25QL_FM_NO_t FM, uint8_t clock_cycles) {
    uint8_t dummy_data[34] = {DUMMY_CLOCKS}; // Max needed cycles is 34
    csLOW(FM);
    SPI_Write(hspi, dummy_data, clock_cycles);
    csHIGH(FM);
}

static void power_loss_recovery(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, MT25QL_FM_NO_t FM) {
    uint8_t dummy_data[8] = {DUMMY_CLOCKS};
    csLOW(FM);
    SPI_Write(hspi, dummy_data, 8);
    csHIGH(FM);
    //HAL_Delay(1); // Ensure tSHSL2 >= 50ns
}

static void interface_rescue(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, MT25QL_FM_NO_t FM) {
    uint8_t dummy_data[16] = {DUMMY_CLOCKS};
    csLOW(FM);
    SPI_Write(hspi, dummy_data, 16);
    csHIGH(FM);
    //HAL_Delay(1); // Ensure tSHSL2 >= 50ns
}


all functions are void and you never check for errors. So basically you do not care if the operation fails. Extremely bad. Remember - sometimes 70% of the code deals with errors, 30% does something logical

You show the function that fails (MT25QL_WriteNONVOL), but you don't show where it is called. You didn't show that you verified that bit reverse function works (but I take it it works in others parts of the program?). Please, check what exactly is being sent out over SPI to the non-volatile config reg. You could have enabled QuadSPI or changed output driver impedance by accident. Since this is a non-volatile config register, this would also explain why the problem stays after power cycle.

ISSUE: Nonvolatile Configuration Register was set to an undetermined state due to a logical error in the code after sending a write nonvolatile configuration register command.
SOLUTION: Run power loss recovery sequence which may be done by using SCK, DQ0, and DQ3 pins as GPIO and running the functions provided in the linked solution.
SOLUTION HERE
